# Can I still rely on the order of the output elements when using par_unseq?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parallel-processing, c++17

After reading the documentation I'm still confused about the usage of `par_unseq`. I know I can't tell anything about the order of execution because of threading and vectorization but can I still rely on the order of the outputs?

```
transform([x0, x1, x2], f) == [f(x0), f(x1), f(x2)]]
```

In order words, is this test ever going to fail?

```
std::vector<int> xs = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::vector<int> ys(xs.size());

std::transform(
    std::execution::par_unseq,
    cbegin(xs), cend(xs),
    begin(ys),
    [](int x) { return x*x; });

std::vector<int> expected = {1, 4, 9, 16};
ASSERT_EQ(expected , ys);
```

Comment: As I understand it, the order of the outputs of `std::transform` is part of its specification, and it should not change no matter the execution policy that is chosen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Standard, [[alg.transform]](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.transform#2), reads:

> *Effects:* Assigns through every iterator `i` in the range `[result,result + (last1 - first1))` a new corresponding value equal to `op(*(first1 + (i - result))` or `binary_op(*(first1 + (i - result)), *(first2 + (i - result)))`.

and (thanks, @Caleth), [[algorithms.parallel.overloads]](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#overloads-2):

> Unless otherwise specified, the semantics of `ExecutionPolicy` algorithm overloads are identical to their overloads without.

So, yes, you can rely on the order in the output.

Comment: You also have ["Unless otherwise specified, the semantics of ExecutionPolicy algorithm overloads are identical to their overloads without"](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#overloads-2) in [algorithms.parallel.overloads]

Comment: Thanks, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform doesn't mention this behavior but is seems that the standard is very clear on this

Answer (score 2):

No, your test is never going to fail because even if order of execution changes, 
`ys[0...3] = xs[0...3] * xs[0...3] = {1*1, 2*2, 3*3, 4*4};`
won't change.